# Distance over a space of functions on a finite measure space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Some idea for dealing with this problem? Let $(X,\Omega, \mu)$ a finite measure space and $M$ the set of measurable functions over $X$. Prove that $$d(f,g)=\int\frac{|f-g|}{1+|f-g|}d\mu$$
Defines a complete metric over $M$. I don't know how to proceed to show the completeness. Thank you all.

Comment: There are many posts on this problem. Please have a look at them first.

Comment: Would you link me to one of them? I've been searching for them and I didn't success. Thanks

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753533/is-this-space-complete?rq=1

Comment: Proof is essentially the same.